# Can't configure $batch endpoint for OData Web service exposed with ASP .Net Web Api to Lightswitch

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a problem of setting up an OData web service with ASP .NET Web API. I need to provide that service as a data source to Lightswitch. Get requests work normally but when I try POST - this is where I got stuck.

**The Error**

In Lightswitch I get the error:

**{"Message":"The batch request must have 'multipart/mixed' as the media type."}**

when invoking an add/edit command.

As Lightswitch requires $batch endpoint, I installed the latest RC version of Web API that supports them. Also before starting to configure the batch end point I followed the tutorials at: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Then I followed this tutorial to setup the batch endpoint: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20API%20Request%20Batching

I reviwed this post: [How to create / where the batch endpoint is for an asp.net OData webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211914/how-to-create-where-the-batch-endpoint-is-for-an-asp-net-odata-webservice) and managed to make the project compile with DefaultODataBatchHandler. Still I can't make batch requests/response work.

### Details of the scenario I tried:

Request/Responce - data from Fiddler

**Request sent from Lightswich Client:**

```
POST http://localhost:3352/ContainerData.svc/$batch HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
Accept: multipart/mixed
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_730c-bd5b-40de
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
Referer: http://localhost:3352/HTMLClient/
Accept-Language: en-GB
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 535
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:3352
Pragma: no-cache


--batch_730c-bd5b-40de
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_2952-4c78-0ea1

--changeset_2952-4c78-0ea1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST ServiceProviders HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 0
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
Content-Type: application/json
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

{"ID":2,"CategoryID":1,"Name":"fdfdrer","Description":"fefdf"}
--changeset_2952-4c78-0ea1--

--batch_730c-bd5b-40de--
```

**Responce of Web API:**

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 2886
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_663f69c3-6315-447b-b179-00bf407c3b09
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcdmd0MWcxMlxEb2N1bWVudHNcVmlzdWFsIFN0dWRpbyAyMDEyXFByb2plY3RzXE1ha2VZb3VyQ2hvaWNlXE1ha2VZb3VyQ2hvaWNlVUlcTWFrZVlvdXJDaG9pY2VVSVxCaW5cRGVidWdcQ29udGFpbmVyRGF0YS5zdmNcJGJhdGNo?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 05 Jul 2013 11:01:49 GMT

--batchresponse_663f69c3-6315-447b-b179-00bf407c3b09
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_d1537003-f0cd-4fe2-b4b1-2f562b3179d0

--changesetresponse_d1537003-f0cd-4fe2-b4b1-2f562b3179d0
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-ID: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8

{"error":{"code":"1","message":{"lang":"en-GB","value":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><ExceptionInfo><Message>One or more of the changes failed to save.  To ensure consistency, refresh and re-apply your changes.\r\nInner exception message:\r\nAn error occurred while processing this request.\r\nInner exception message:\r\n{\"Message\":\"The batch request must have 'multipart/mixed' as the media type.\"}</Message><StackTrace>
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataProvider.AstoriaDataServiceDataProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;SubmitCore&gt;b__0()\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataProvider.AstoriaDataServiceDataProvider.InvokeAstoriaOperation(DataServiceContext context, Action astoriaOperation)\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataProvider.AstoriaDataServiceDataProvider.SubmitCore(IEnumerable`1 changes)\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataProvider.DataProvider.Submit(IEnumerable`1 changes)\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceImplementation`1.PerformPersistCore(IEnumerable`1 eventsChangeSetItems)\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceImplementation`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass46.&lt;PerformPersist&gt;b__45()\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.DualDispatcherObject.Mutate(IDispatcher logicDispatcher, MutatorHost host, Action mutator)\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceImplementation`1.PerformPersist(IEnumerable`1 eventsChangeSetItems)\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceImplementation`1.Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.IServerDataServiceImplementationCore.Submit()\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataService`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClasse.&lt;Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.IODataService.SaveChanges&gt;b__c()\r\n
at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceImplementation`1.InvokeOperationCore[T](String operationName, Object[] args, Boolean invokedFromODataClient, Func`1 invokeOperation, Action catchCallback, Action`2 serializeCustomExceptionInfo)</StackTrace><ErrorInfo /></ExceptionInfo>"}}}
--changesetresponse_d1537003-f0cd-4fe2-b4b1-2f562b3179d0--
--batchresponse_663f69c3-6315-447b-b179-00bf407c3b09--
```

**Log from Web API:**

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=POST,    Url=http://localhost:3346/odata/$batch, Message='http://localhost:3346/odata/$batch'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:3346/odata/ServiceProviders, Message='http://localhost:3346/odata/ServiceProviders'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=InspectHandler.SendAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=400 (BadRequest), Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:3346/odata/ServiceProviders, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=InspectHandler.SendAsync, Status=202 (Accepted)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=202 (Accepted), Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:3346/odata/$batch, Message='Content-type='multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_580061e2-8dc6-4676-b207-1b6ad0ff8847', content-length=unknown'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
```

Comment: Note - I tested batch operations with different clients, notably WCF Data Services Client framework. I tried scenarios of several get requests in batch - and still the error is the aforementioned. I think the problem is in passing of information between IIS and the web api controller. For some reason the controller can't intercept any call in a batch operation. Also the Lightswitch client works fine with a service that used WCF Data Services API.